# How to receive data packets in Android emulator and phone

Tags: java, android, udp

I'm trying to receive some udp packets from a PC and it's not working. I have a [activity](http://pastebin.com/BiSDRctY), a [receive thread](http://pastebin.com/4BztabE3) and a [server thread](http://pastebin.com/ADU9U5tC). The 57111 port is redirected in the emulator. I start the receive thread first and afterwards the server thread, any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have done that using an external socket simulator "SocketTest v 3.0.0" and a port redirection by telnet  it's more realistic and more simple than alternate between `Server` and `reviever` in the same Application. So if you want to proceed like that:

1. download the `SocketTest` it's free
2. run your android app (just the server thread)
3. do a telnet redirection from your host :

   ```
   Telnet localhost <Port of you'r emulator> (5554 for me)
   redir add udp:5000:6000
   ```
4. go to udp in the `SocketTest` and send a udp message to the 5000 port

If your listner works fine you will catch the message, I hope that helps.

Regards

Comment: Can you provide a link for SocketTest?

Comment: I already redirected with telnet 57111 to 57111 as I wrote in the question, and the application doesn't receive any messages, there is no error on the android side, without the timeout it just blocks in the receive method, I really have no idea

Comment: What adresse do you use in the android side ?

Comment: The full code is available in the description I posted it on paste bin "activity, a receive thread and a server thread" there are links to each of the classes publicly available. On the android side I just listen on 57111. When I run my server and receive thread on just pc with sockettest they both work, but on the android side it blocks forever. I mention again that there are links to paste bin where the full classes are available .